# Cron job in phpbb?

Tags: cron, phpbb

I have phpbb installation with some automatic scripts set up but I don't know how are they run. There's "cron" folder in root directory and there are those scripts in it. The thing is that I haven't used cron job before and I don't know how to create them. Can I set them up from cpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the cron jobs so the scripts run using CPanel.  [Here is a tutorial](http://calendarscripts.info/cron-jobs-tutorial.html) explaining how to do it.

Edit: Updated the link to point to a better summary.